# Use activeadmin_dynamic_fields to control multiple inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working with ActiveAdmin in a Rails application. I'm admittedly new to Ruby and Active Admin. I'm used to JavaScript development. I couldn't find a way to enable or disable fields based on the value of another field. I ended up finding and installing the gem activeadmin_dynamic_fields to allow that. I was able to use a single checkbox to hide or show another field like so:

```
      f.input :is_promo, label: 'Is this a promotion?', as: :boolean,
              input_html: {
                data: { if: 'not_checked', action: 'hide', target: '.disclaimer'}
              }
```

The problem comes if I try to control more than one field with the same checkbox. I've tried:

```
      f.input :is_promo, label: 'Is this a promotion?', as: :boolean,
              input_html: {
                data: {
                  { if: 'not_checked', action: 'hide', target: '.disclaimer'},
                  { if: 'not_checked', action: 'hide', target: '.terms-required'},
                  { if: 'checked', action: 'hide', target: '.terms-not-required'}
                }
            }
```

as well as:

```
      f.input :is_promo, label: 'Is this a promotion?', as: :boolean,
              input_html: {[
                  data: {{ if: 'not_checked', action: 'hide', target: '.disclaimer'}},
                  data:{{ if: 'not_checked', action: 'hide', target: '.terms-required'}},
                  data: {{ if: 'checked', action: 'hide', target: '.terms-not-required'}}
              ]}
            }
```

However, nothing seems to work. If I can't get this to work with activeadmin_dynamic_fields, then I would like to try to get it to work with regular ActiveAdmin. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there might not be a solution to this with the limitations of this gem. I ended up just using jQuery instead.